# In Automator, why are slashes in my file path being replaced with colons?

Tags: applescript, automator

I am trying to make an automator workflow, and I have a file path in a variable.  I use this variable by accessing it with a "Get Value of Variable" block and pass the result as an argument to a "Run Applescript" Block.  The "Run Applescript" block just opens a terminal window and passes the value of the variable as an argument to a script (dd if it matters).

Somewhere along the line, my file path is being messed up.  All of the slashes are turning into colons (e.g. "...//Documents/Stuff"  becomes "...::Documents:Stuff").

Why is this happening and how can I stop it from happening?

Comment: It is certainly "happening" because it is following the instructions you are giving it. There are two types of path descriptions for OSX, the legacy ":" based paths, and the unix style "/" Posix paths. The colon-delineated style is assumed by Applescript unless you specify Posix path. We have to see your code and/or the screen shot of your workflow to be able to pinpoint where the unintentional coercion is taking place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jweaks said in a comment:

> There are two types of path descriptions for OSX, the legacy ":" based
>   paths, and the unix style "/" Posix paths. The colon-delineated style
>   is assumed by Applescript unless you specify Posix path.

Using `POSIX file` results in slashes being used, but just `file` results in colons being used.

Answer (score 1):

If I have to guess the automator by default create file paths with "/". Try to add a line to the start of your "run applescript" to change it back to ":".

```
set YourVariable to (POSIX file (YourVariable)) as string
```